# How can I turn this into an Ansible Playbook?

Tags: ansible

I'm very, very new to Ansible so I just need someone to break down how to set up a yaml file to use as a playbook.

I wrote this string of code that does work:

```
ansible Test --user exampleuser --ask-pass -c local -m ping
```

Output:

```
192.168.1.4 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
```

How to I format what I wrote so I can just type:

```
ansible-playbook test.yaml
```

Comment: you can start [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ping_module.html?highlight=ping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the content of yaml file should look like

```
---
- hosts: Test
  connection: local
  remote_user: exampleuser
  tasks:
    - ping:
```

Comment: Thank you! I was confused as to where "ping" should go.